# Paper.js - Get first ''selected item'' from selectedItems

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm trying my way around building a graphics editor with **[Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)**

I would like to **select the *first(1st) element* that was picked using a *selection tool***(either Shift+Click, or dragging a selection box). Direct-click detection is done via [hit-testing](http://paperjs.org/reference/hitresult/) and selection box via [getIntersection](http://paperjs.org/reference/pathitem/#getintersections%28path,%20sorted%29-path)

- If it's **Shift+Click** its the **first selected element**. Which element was clicked is found with [HitResult](http://paperjs.org/reference/hitresult/)
- If its **selectionBox,** the [**first intersection?**](http://scriptographer.org/reference/ai/pathitem#intersect-item) result of the selection box.

Is it possible to get this?

I do a FOR loop to get all the elements in the **[Paper.js selectedItems](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#selecteditems)** array which returns all the selected items on the canvas.

I've tried this:

```
var selected = paper.project.selectedItems;
var firstSelected = selected[0];
```

but this doesn't return what i need.

The above code snippet fetches an **[array](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#selecteditems)** that is agnostic to which element was selected first. ***It simply orders the [selectedItems](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#selecteditems) in the array starting from the ''oldest drawn path''.***

What i need is a way to find out **which is the 1st element that was selected.**

- Either the 1st that get's ''[touched(intersected)](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getintersections%28path,%20sorted%29-path)'' with the selection
  rectangle
- Or the first that was clicked while in [Shift+Click](http://paperjs.org/reference/hitresult/)
  functionality(Select more than one element with click).

**The reason for this is that i would like to add to my *editor*, align-relative-to functionality.**

In order to have a correct UX, the user must have the ability to align an element relative to another that he sets as the ''reference item''. Therefore i need to know the 1st element selected relative to others in order to use it as the ''reference item''.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio/workspace/SelectPaperJS/PathEditing.html) is a working example of what I understood you want to achieve for the selection (without the align-relative-to functionality).
And here is the code (under SelectPaperJS) https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio/

It should not be too hard to make something similar on [Stylii](https://github.com/memononen/stylii) (since you're using it).

You can have an array to keep track of the order of selection of your items. For example in the mousedown function of the direct select tool (from line 789 of editor.js) you can add the newly selected element to this array (line 800). Same thing when you select with the rectangular selection tool.

Comment: Arthur, what does this line of code do?:  if(newSegments.indexOf(selectionItems[i])>=0)
continue;

Comment: It checks if the selected item at index i is in the newSegments array. If so, it continues iterating the loop without going further at this iteration. (That is all I can tell you without having the context, where did you find this line?)